# Theoretical returns are not matching empirical ones in my backtest

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, returns, backtesting, short-selling, equity-curve

I'm trying to implement a Backtest for my quant strategy but the calculated theoretical returns are not matching the returns from my implementation. Here's the example:

On a given day I have 1 million dollars available to trade and my model tells me to start a short selling operation. Also, on this day, the Mean and the Close prices of the asset I'm trading are, respectively, 38740 and 38569.1. Therefore, I start by operating (1 million)/38740 = 25,81311306 shares (I suppose that the price of acquisition is the Mean and that any fraction of the share can be bought). Since it is a short selling operation I have now 2 millions dollars (1 million I already had plus the 1 million that I got for renting 25,81311306 shares and selling them).

To calculate my equity at the end of the day I use the formula Equity = Cash available - (Number of shares operated) * (Closing Price of the asset) = 2 million - 25,81311306 * 38569.1 = 1004411,461. However, my 'theoretical' return at the end of this day is Mean/Close = 38740/38569.1 = 1,004431008. Multiplying this return by the initial 1 million I get 1004431,008, which is different from the previously calculated value of 1004411,461. Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want Close/Mean as your return (=valuation price / price at which the position was opened).

Comment: 38569.1/38740 - 1 = -0.004411461 . Because the opertion is a Short sale your return is the negative of this or 0.004411461.